Deriving equations for Hermite polynomial derivatives and recursion
Having already proven the following relations of Hermite polynomials:
$$
\frac{d}{dx} (e^{-x^2/2}H_n(x)) = -e^{-x^2/2}H_{n+1}(x)
$$
and
$$
H_n'(x) = xH_n(x) - H_{n+1}(x)
$$
I am trying to prove $\langle H_n', H_m \rangle = \langle H_n, H_{m+1} \rangle$.
Using integration by parts on the inner product defined by $L^2(-\infty, \infty; e^{-x^2/2})$:
$$
\langle H_n', H_m \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^\infty H_n' H_m e^{-x^2/2} dx
$$
Using integration by parts:
Let $u = H_m(x)$ and therefore $du = H_m'(x) dx$
and $dv = H_n'(x) e^{-x^2/2} dx$. Evaluating $v$:
$$
v = \int_{-\infty}^\infty H_n' e^{-x^2/2} dx = \\
\int_{-\infty}^\infty xH_n(x) e^{-x^2/2} dx -  \int_{-\infty}^\infty H_{n+1}(x) e^{-x^2/2} dx
$$
My understanding is that the term on the left is:
$$
\int x H_n(x) e^{-x^2/2}dx = \begin{cases}0 & n \ne 1\\ \sqrt{2\pi} & n = 1\end{cases}
$$
by the orthogonality of the Hermite polynomials.
However, following this understanding through for $n\ne1$, I continue integration by parts:
$$
\langle H_n', H_m \rangle = \\ [H_m H_n e^{-x^2/2}]_{-\infty}^\infty - \int_{-\infty}^\infty H_n H_m' e^{-x^2/2}dx=\\0 - (\langle H_n, xH_m\rangle - \langle H_n, H_{m+1} \rangle)
$$
but
$$
\langle H_n(x), xH_m(x) \rangle = \\\int_{-\infty}^\infty H_n xH_m e^{-x^2/2}dx = \begin{cases}0 & \vert m -n \vert \gt 1 \\ \sqrt{2\pi} n ! & m = n - 1 \\ \sqrt{2\pi} m! & m = n + 1 \\ ? & m = n\end{cases}
$$
Putting the last case aside, it seems to me this inner product is not always $0$, which contrasts with the equation we sought to prove.
Where did I go wrong here?

It is easier and more straightforward to integrate by parts with the reverse choice, i.e. with $u' = H_m'(x)$ and $v = H_n(x)e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}$.

I still can't point out the original integration by parts broke down in the original post, but as pointed out by @Abezhiko, the problem is straightforward choosing a different $dv$ and $u$.
Integrate by parts.
Let $dv = H_n' \Rightarrow v = H_n$.
Let $u = H_m(x)\cdot e^{-x^2/2}$ and evaluate the integral:
$$
du = \\ [H_m' \cdot e^{-x^2/2} - x H_m e^{-x^2/2}]dx = \\ [(x H_m - H_{m+1}) \cdot e^{-x^2/2} - x H_m e^{-x^2/2}]dx = \\ [-H_{m+1} e^{-x^2/2}]dx
$$
Complete integration by parts:
$$
\langle H_n', H_m \rangle = \\H_m H_n e^{-x^2/2} \vert_{-\infty}^\infty - \int_{-\infty}^\infty H_n [-H_{m+1} e^{-x^2/2}]dx = \\ \langle H_n, H_{m+1} \rangle
$$

This is a “What went wrong?” question, not a “How to do it?” question.

One interpretation of what went wrong given the stated goal to prove: $\langle H_n', H_m \rangle = \langle H_n, H_{m+1} \rangle$ is to choose a more straightforward  and  , but I agree this doesn't identify what statement in the question body is technically wrong. I've tried to make this clear in the answer body and accordingly didn't accept this answer. Here I just wanted to provide an explicit elaboration for @Abezhiko's comment. I've no great stake in this answer, so I can delete it if it's somehow misleading.
